# error: expected identifier before ‘public’, expected ‘{’ before ‘public’

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors

I'm getting this weird error, which I'm not able to resolve.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public:BaseClass(const char* aHow = NULL)
    {
        std::strcpy(ivHow,aHow);
    }

    char ivHow[512];
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    DerivedClass (const char* dcHow):BaseClass (dcHow){}
};
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
../trunk/inc/Sample.h: In constructor ‘DerivedClass::DerivedClass(const char*)’:
../trunk/inc/Sample.h: error: expected identifier before ‘public’
../trunk/inc/Sample.h: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘public’
```

Comment: Are you sure you get those errors from that code? The only error here is that `BaseClass` has a private constructor, inaccessible from the `DerivedClass` constructor.

Comment: And it can be improved by using `std::string` instead of char arrays, but that's not the cause of the error either.

Comment: It sounds like, in your code, `BaseClass` hasn't been defined before `DerivedClass`. Is it in a separate header? Are you including that header? Is the header properly guarded? Better still, could we see the exact code that you're compiling?

Comment: Sorry all.. For not mentioning "public:". Base Class' constructor is public.

Comment: -1 for posting code that you haven't tested. The given code will not cause the error you have posted.

Comment: Come one @codinonwheels, why don't you update your question to a valid one? You can't seriously be satisfied with this (and I'm waiting for a problem to fix here ;-) )

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare the constructor of BaseClass `public`. By doing so, the members of the class are accessible from anywhere where the object is visible, like that:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public: // or protected
    BaseClass(const char* aHow = NULL)
    {
    std::strcpy(ivHow,aHow);
    }
};
```

All of the data members of a class are setted as `private` by default, so they are only accessible  from within other members of the same class or from their [friends](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).

As pointed out by Ivaylo Strandjev on comments, the construct could be setted as `protected` aswell, since

> protected members are accessible from members of their same class and from their friends, but also from members of their derived classes.

Comment: Actually a protected constructor will suffice here

Answer (score 1):

By default the members are private, do

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected: //or public
    BaseClass(const char* aHow = NULL)
    {
        std::strcpy(ivHow,aHow);
    }

    char ivHow[512];
};
```